# How to select ASCII characters, using a Samsung keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-6

On my computer, I regularly type French, German and other characters, using their ASCII code, such as:

- ± : ASCII code 177
- Ç : ASCII code 199
- œ : ASCII code 156
- ß : ASCII code 223

On a computer, this is fairly simple, using the following keyboard shortcuts:<kbd>Alt+0177</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+0199</kbd>, <kbd>Alt+0156</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+0223</kbd>.

How can I type those characters on a Samsung Galaxy smartphone, using the standard Samsung keyboard?

Comment: No idea about the Samsung keyboard but you can customize AnySoftKeyboard according to your needs. [I did the same](https://github.com/mirfatif/AnySoftKeyboard) to add multiple Unicode characters which I use quite often.

Answer (score 1):

On Samsung, you need to hold down the character associated with it. For example, if you want to input Ç on the keyboard, hold down the regular c, and a display of special variants of c will be shown. Guide your finger to the special character while holding the screen and let go when it highlights the character or when your finger is touching it.

Boom, you have your character. As for characters like ß which are on their own and aren't special variants like Ç, use the letter that sounds like it. ß is pronounced like "sh" or "ss", so hold s and select ß.

Comment: I've managed typing the "Ç", the "ß" and the "œ" by holding the keys 'C', 's' and 'o' down, but do you know how to type '±'?

Comment: @Dominique You do the same with the + symbol. As I said, variants of a letter or the phonetic sound of a letter usually match the corresponding location of the symbol. C leads to Ç, and so forth. In this case, it's the + symbol. This is on my samsung, so it's not the same version but the keyboards do seem to be synchronized across versions.

Comment: When keeping the "+" pressed, no extra characters are shown. I have Samsung keyboard version 3.5.45.2, it mentions that the latest version is already installed.